# A question on continuous mappings

Tags: gn.general-topology

The question is also posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377990/a-question-on-continuous-mappings).

Let $M=\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau_M=\lbrace U\cup A: U$ open in $\mathbb{R}, A\subset \mathbb{R} \setminus B\rbrace$, where $B$ is a [Bernstein set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377990/a-question-on-continuous-mappings). Then $(M,\tau_M)$ is a topological space called the **Michael Line**. It is a regular Lindelof space.

**Submetrizable** = if we can choose a coarser topology on the space $X$ and thus make it a metrizable space.

> Let $f: M \to X$ be any one-to-one and onto continuous mapping. Then is $X$ always submetrizable?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why must we consider the homeomorphic image rather than the $M$ itself? Is there any background?

Comment: Buzyakova posted a new definition of absolutely submetrizable (= every Tychonoff subtopology is submetrizable) in the paper: On absolutely submetrizable spaces